# Ignoring events that fire repeatedly

Tags: java, events, swing, concurrency

I have some code that responds to a `PropertyChangeEvent`. The problem with this event is that it can be fired in succession a few times or not at all. It is not predictable whether this event is fired just once or multiple times, and I am not in control of how this event is fired. I would like the event listener to be fired only once.

My solution to this problem is to use a class I wrote called `DelayedRunnable`. I wrap the listener in a `DelayedRunnable`. When the event is first fired, the listener is scheduled to be executed after one second--an amount of time I arbitrarily decided. Subsequent firings of events are ignored until that one second has elapsed. Here is the code for `DelayedRunnable`:

```
public class DelayedRunnable implements Runnable {
    final Runnable                 runnable;
    final int                      delayAmount;
    final TimeUnit                 delayUnit;
    final ScheduledExecutorService service         = new ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(1);
    final Runnable                 executeRunnable = new ExecuteRunnable();
    final AtomicBoolean            scheduled       = new AtomicBoolean(false);

    public DelayedRunnable(Runnable runnable, int delayAmount, TimeUnit delayUnit) {
        if (runnable == null)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("runnable == null");
        this.runnable = runnable;
        this.delayAmount = delayAmount;
        this.delayUnit = delayUnit;
    }

    public void run() {
        if (!scheduled.compareAndSet(false, true))
            return;
        service.schedule(executeRunnable, delayAmount, delayUnit);
    }

    class ExecuteRunnable implements Runnable {
        public void run() {
            runnable.run();
            scheduled.set(false);
        }
    }
}
```

When I wrap the listener in `DelayedRunnable`, it gets called only once. An ancillary  benefit of the `DelayedRunnable` is that the listener code is not executed on the Swing EDT, as the listener code is expensive.

However I find that sometimes the listener is never called, perhaps due to concurrency issues in `DelayedRunnable`. When I restart the application, the listener magically works again. As one would expect, I am unable to reproduce the situations where `DelayedRunnable` fails to work due to the nature of concurrent programming. Additionally, the one second time limit is completely arbitrarily. On some computers, one second may not be enough. On other computers, one second is too long. There is no straightforward way of setting the time limit.

I have two questions:

- Does anyone know of the problems with `DelayedRunnable` that I am unable to see?
- Is there a more elegant way of dealing with this problem than resorting to this `DelayedRunnable` approach?

Comment: See [Issues With Application Design](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/index-142890.html#5).

Comment: trashgod, I am not able to control how events are fired. Moreover, the issue is not that events are being fired back and forth forever, it's just that the event is unnecessarily and unpredictably being fired more than once.

Comment: When you say, "I am not able to control how events are fired," do you mean 1) you do not have access to the source code that generates the `PropertyChangeEvent` or 2) the event (occasionally) does not arrive when expected? Have you examined the results returned by the event's [methods](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/beans/PropertyChangeEvent.html)?

Comment: the very base sounds fishy: propertyChangeEvents aren't fired arbitrarily, the contract is to fire on a _change_ So before going into stratosphere of threading complexity, I would dig into why/when/what they fire (as @trashgod already suggested, kind of :-)

Answer (score 2):

one thing you should be careful about is doing gui work outside of the EDT.  since the *actual* runnable is run on a new thread (inside the executor service), it cannot do any gui work directly.

it's possible that one of your runnables is getting hung, and therefore any future executions are getting blocked.

Comment: +1 for valid points. Agree, probable cause of failure is wrapped runnable is hanging preventing `scheduled` flag from being cleared; there's no suggestion that GUI work is being done in the wrapped runnable and OP shows indications that he's aware of this, but good point anyway.

Comment: GUI code is being wrapped in `SwingUtilities.invokeLater()`, but the main thrust of the listener is not to do GUI updating. It's also not clear _why_ runnables are hanging.

Comment: Maybe try adding some tracing to your wrapped Runnables to see where they are stuck.

Comment: @Samad - if you suspect a hung thread, then the logical next step is to get a stack dump of the program when it is not functioning correctly.  this will show you where your listener is hung.

Comment: What open source tools would you suggest for debugging concurrency issues like this?

Comment: @Samad - you don't need any special tools to get a stack dump: http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Programming/Stacktrace/

Answer (score 0):

An AWT Event Listener will be executed before other listeners so you can filter the event there first. with something like:

```
something like Container c;
.
.
.
c.addAWTEventListener(new AWTEventListener()
{
    public void eventDispatched(AWTEvent e)
    {
       if(! e instanceof YOUR_EVENT_TYPE)
       return;
       //code to filter here
       e.consume() //to remove if not in time bounds   
    }
});
```

see http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/event/AWTEventListener.html for usage

Comment: `PropertyChangeEvent` is not a subclass of AWTEvent, so I don't see how this will help the poster...but an interesting idea nevertheless!

Comment: I agree with what Kevin K wrote.

Answer (score 0):

As jtahlborn mentions, gui work should be done on the event queue.  Make sure any gui work is wrapped in [EventQueue.invokeAndWait](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/EventQueue.html#invokeAndWait%28java.lang.Runnable%29) or [EventQueue.invokeLater](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/EventQueue.html#invokeLater%28java.lang.Runnable%29).

Actually, depending on the nature of how the events are being generated, you may be able to avoid the delay mechanism entirely using `EventQueue.invokeLater`, because the runnable to be invoked is placed at the end of the queue.  If all of the multiple event callbacks are added to the queue prior to the first callback being run, you can be sure a runnable added to the queue with invokeLater will not see any subsequent events.  Then you can use a flag similar to what you already do in `DelayedRunnable` to ensure you only add a runnable for the first event.

Comment: If I understand this correctly, you are suggesting that the listener set some flag when it starts, then removes the flag when it finishes. If the listener is invoked when the flag is set, the listener ignores the event. The problem with this is that the listener may finish before the second event is fired.

Comment: your GUI doesn't know and nor Listening any Threads invoked by Executor (for example), anyway read http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html and descriptiona about SwingWorker could be your answer, because Executor can start SWingWorker and with "multiThreading in Swing" note 1) carrefully wiht number of live Threads - limit from Executor 2/ Executor + SwingWorker is in Top25 bugs http://bugs.sun.com/top25_bugs.do

Comment: @Samad - the idea is to use the first callback to set the flag and add a Runnable to the end of the event queue using invokeLater, then the Runnable does actual handling for the event and clears the flag.  This skips any subsequent callbacks that are already on the event queue at the time of the first callback.  If the events are programmatically generated this could be the case, but not always.  Definitely not for user triggered events.

Comment: @mKorbel - not quite understanding what you're saying, but good link, and I forgot about SwingWorker